# Manage Display Format options not saving

Tags: 8, display-suite

I'm trying to edit a field label under Product Type > Manage Display. I expand the settings and type in "Product Name" and his "Update" and then scroll to the bottom and his "Save". When I expand the settings again, the Label field is blank again. Any thoughts on why this might not be saving this?[image] Note, it doesn't seem to be working on other node content types either.

Comment: Any errors in `/admin/reports/dblog`? Any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: I had not thought to look at browser console, but I just tried again and nothing there. Nothing in Drupal logs either.